# NativeScript push notifications permission dialog shows behind app

Tags: nativescript

Do you know what could be causing the permissions request dialog on iOS to show behind the app? It actually flashes quickly and then goes behind. I have to press the home button to bring it to the front. Until then the UI is blocked.

I am using Everlive and I am calling the register method in the app's launchEvent as such:

```js
var pushSettings = {
//iOS - specific settings
iOS: {
badge: true,
sound: true,
alert: true,
clearBadge: true
},
notificationCallbackIOS: function (userInfo) {
...
},
//Android - specific settings
android: {
projectNumber: '944301213976'
},
notificationCallbackAndroid: function callback(data) {
...
}
}

el.push.register(pushSettings, function (data) {
    ...
}, function (error) {

});
```

Thank you.

EDIT:  I should add that I am testing on iOS 9.3.4 and right before the dialog goes behind the app, I get the following warning in the console:  enabledRemoteNotificationTypes is not supported in iOS 8.0 and later.  Not sure if it matters, but I wanted to mention it, just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out that it was a timing issue.  I was running the code when the app was initializing.  The popup will get displayed, but shortly after, the first screen (login in my case) gets initialized, stealing the focus from the popup.

Once I moved the code in a button tap event (after the screen loading was completed) everything worked as expected.

I am not sure if this is the best way to handle this.  I am open for suggestions.

Also, you can see https://github.com/NativeScript/push-plugin/issues/38 for more info.  Thank you Anton Dobrev for pointing me to the right direction.